# querying tree/graphs modeled in SQL (Celko)

Tags: php, sql, graph, tree, celko

Do you know any reference where to find SQL queries for traversing trees/graphs?

I found this one: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html and Celko's book.

Problem is that the majority of resources I found refers to adiacency model trees, I'm using a normal edge list model.

Eg. queries or procedures to extract subpaths, subtrees, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm using a convergent graph (one child can have two parents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested sets models are best for hierarchical aggregations. Traversals for general graphs are best done with the adjacency list model. But I have used nested sets for convergent graphs by splitting nodes

```
 A
/ \
B C
\ /
 D
```

Becomes

```
 A
/ \
B C
|  |  
D  D
```

Since nests sets keep nodes in a separate table, this is easy.

You can also do a general graph as a forest of all possible spanning trees

Comment: I'm really glad the author of the book replied! When you say "splitting nodes", do you mean duplicating nodes? I'm thinking to explore graphDB API, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

If your graph is not frequently updated, using a [GRIPP index](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/series/informatik-berichte/207/PDF/207.pdf) will let you handle graph traversal queries extremely well. The latter lets you answer parent-child and depth-related queries in more or less fixed time -- irrespective of the graph's number of nodes or density of links.

Comment: @Denis do you have any practical examples of an implementation of the GRIPP index? All I can find are academid papers on the subject which are pretty hard to convert into practice for non-academic developers.

Comment: @ChrisR: I've implemented it myself once, for a side project, but I'm afraid I've no idea where the code is off the top of my head. That said, I seem to recollect me of the academic papers offering pseudo code for a stored procedure, and this is easier to implement than the path I chose myself (using triggers).